# How to Insert Multiple Checkboxes and their Textfields Into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in the field of PHP.
 I am working on a form to get information from a patient regarding a specific disease.
In this form i have multiple check-boxes and text fields with each check-box. If one check bos is checked then values of its text fields and checkbox values has to insert in database.
Please tell me the code to insert checked values along with textfields into database.

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Past Medical History:</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td colspan="4" height="290"><table border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="26%"><div align="center">Problem</div></td>
<td width="18%"><div align="center">From (Year)</div></td>
<td width="56%"><div align="center">Details</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="chkBP" id="chkBP" value="BP" type="checkbox" />
 Blood Pressure</td>
 <td><div align="center">
 <input name="txtBPfrom" id="txtBPfrom" size="15" value="" type="text" />
 </div></td>
 <td><input name="txtBPDetail" id="txtBPDetail" size="40" value="" type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input name="chkDiabetes" id="chkDiabetes" value="Diabetes" type="checkbox" />
 Diabetes</td>
 <td><div align="center">
 <input name="txtDiabetesfrom" id="txtDiabetesfrom" size="15" value="" type="text" />
 </div></td>
 <td><input name="txtDiabetesDetail" id="txtDiabetesDetail" size="40" value=""   type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input name="chkHighCholes" id="chkHighCholes" value="HighCholesterol" type="checkbox" />
 High Cholesterol</td>
 <td><div align="center">
 <input name="txtHighCholesfrom" id="txtHighCholesfrom" size="15" value="" type="text"/>
 </div></td>
 <td><input name="txtHighCholesDetail" id="txtHighCholesDetail" size="40" value="" type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input name="chkArthritis" id="chkArthritis" value="Arthritis" type="checkbox" />
 Arthritis</td>
 <td><div align="center">
 <input name="txtArthritisfrom" id="txtArthritisfrom" size="15" value="" type="text" />
 </div></td>
 <td><input name="txtArthritisDetail" id="txtArthritisDetail" size="40" value="" type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input name="chkAsthma" id="chkAsthma" value="Asthma" type="checkbox" />
 Asthma</td>
 <td><div align="center">
 <input name="txtAsthmafrom" id="txtAsthmafrom" size="15" value="" type="text" />
 </div></td>
 <td><input name="txtAsthmaDetail" id="txtAsthmaDetail" size="40" value="" type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input name="chkCirculation" id="chkCirculation" value="Circulation" type="checkbox" />
Circulation</td>
<td><div align="center">
<input name="txtCirculationfrom" id="txtCirculationfrom" size="15" value="" type="text" />
</div></td>
<td><input name="txtCirculationDetail" id="txtCirculationDetail" size="40" value="" type="text" /></td>
</tr>   
</table></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to establish a connection to the database.

When the form is posted collect this data and insert into the database accordingly using $_POST.

Helpful example can be found here to [connect](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

And to insert data

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","web_table");

mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO web_formitem (`ID`, `formID`, `caption`, `key`,    `sortorder`, `type`, `enabled`, `mandatory`, `data`)
VALUES (105, 7, 'Tip izdelka (6)', 'producttype_6', 42, 5, 1, 0, 0)") 
or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Sorry Sir i can't understand that how values of text fields based on checkbox will be inserted into database.

Comment: within a <form method="post" action=""><input type="checkbox" name="test" /><input type="submit" value="submit"/></form> when the form button is hit using the $_POST will look for all form elements submitted so i.e. in the example above $_POST['test'] if checked you will see 1 if not checked then blank you can then associate this data into your DB

Comment: and sir what about the text fields which are associated with checkbox?

Comment: Same thing it just looks for the name='' element of that given field

Comment: sir please can you give me the code for 2 checkbox and its corresponding text fields?

Answer (score 0):

first add any method attribute to your form tag like, `get` or `post`

```
<form>
```

to 
`<form action= "" method="post">`

and add a submit button too in your form
now on submit your form will post your form value
and you can catch them by php as to insert in database

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn_name']))
{
//your database connect
//catch all value, for example
$val=$_POST['check_value'];

//your insert query
}
?>
```

Comment: But sir i only want to insert specific values not all in database. The values for which user check the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox will only post when it's checked.
A textfield will always get posted even when it's empty.

Use a form:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
```

Add a submit button:

```
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
 //var_dump($_POST);
 $chkBP = $_POST['chkBP'];
 $txtBPfrom = $_POST['txtBPfrom'];
 $txtBPDetail = $_POST['txtBPDetail'];
 //echo "-- $txtBPfrom $txtBPDetail --";
 if ($chkBP == "BP"){
     //echo"Bloodpressure = checked";
     $sql="INSERT INTO patient_details (from, detail)
    VALUES ('$txtBPfrom', '$txtBPDetail')";
    mysql_query($sql);
 }else{
     echo"Bloodpressure = not checked";
 }
?>
```

Demo: [here](http://stackoverflow.vergelijkgel.nl/questions/22906754.php)

Comment: ok then if checkbox is checked what code i have to write to insert text fields values of that check box?

Comment: You have to connect to your database. Do you have a table in your database for this?

Comment: Yes Sir i have table name patient_details. And know how to establish a connection. Please sir just tell me how i can insert values of text field if checkbox is checked in database.

Comment: yourbpfromfieldfield, yourbpfromdetailfield need to be renamed to the names u set in the database.

Comment: Ok bpfrom= "from" and bpfromdetail="detail". Now please sir tell me the code

Comment: Any errors? What's wrong with it? Are you understanding our answers?
I think u need to consider learning some basic html & php because it's almost impossible to teach you something. Even the html you posted works but is super messy. For example: U use a table in a table and close a tr after u closed the table.

Comment: may be it is due to some typing mistake but sir i have learnt these things. I am graduate from a reputed university.